# SwiftUI replace and copy text TextEditor

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have read countless articles and watched 10 hours of YouTube videos and still can't figure this out, maybe I'm just missing the term. I'm old school and still trying to learn this backwards swift stuff compared to vb or javascript.

I am using the default Mac OS document template in Xcode 13.1. it comes with a dialogue to open a file then dumps it into the TextEditor as `utf8` string.

For my part I added another TextEditor and a button but keep getting error when I try to copy the text from the original texteditor to the new texteditor when button is pressed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Binding var document: test2Document
    @State var newtexteditor: String = "press the button"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            //main text editor
            TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            //divider
            Divider()
            //new text editor
            TextEditor(text: $newtexteditor).padding()
            //button
            Button("test", action: dosomething)
        }
    }
    
    
    func dosomething () {   
        $newtexteditor = $document   
    }
}
```

Also, is there any ways of giving objects a name or label and using that to say things like `textbox1.text = textbox2.text` like you could using storyboards. I obviously know that's not swift syntax but you get the point.

Comment: What's the new text editor for? Anyway, instead of `$newtexteditor = $document`, you probably meant `newtexteditor = document.text`. This sets the string itself.

Comment: aheze that fixed it. thank you can't believe I didn't try that. the texteditor is just me trying to teach myself. Just out of curiosity do you know if you can retrieve text from an object by using name or identifier like other programming languages can? or is that dead is swiftui?

Comment: By "object" do you mean an on-screen element? Yeah, in SwiftUI that's not how it works. Each object is tied to an `@State` property, and whenever that property changes, the screen will auto update. The property (in your case, a `document.text`) is guaranteed to be exactly what is displayed. So just directly reference `document.text` whenever you need it.

Comment: Aheze. Thank you so much that clears up allot. Do you want to submit the answer newtexteditor = document.text so you can get credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@State` and `@Binding` vars are special kinds of variables. They actually contain 2 sub-variables: [`projectedValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/projectedvalue) and [`wrappedValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/wrappedvalue).

`projectedValue` is like a reference to the actual value, and allows the `@State`/`@Binding` to be modified from further down the view hierarchy.

- You access this by saying `$newTextEditor` or `$document.text`.
- This is only used for passing references down the view hierarchy, where you can later set the `wrappedValue`.

`wrappedValue` is the actual value — in your case, a `String`.

- You access this by just saying `newTextEditor` or `document.text`. No `$`.
- You're able to set this - for example, `newTextEditor = "New text"` or `newTextEditor = document.text`. The UI will automatically update to reflect the changes.

Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Hello"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The text is: \(text)") /// display the `wrappedValue`
            SubView(text: $text) /// pass in the `projectedValue`
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click me to change text") {
            text = "New text" /// set the `wrappedValue`
        }
    }
}
```

In your code, it would look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Binding var document: Test2Document /// Side Note: structs like `Test2Document` should be Capitalized
    @State var newTextEditor: String = "press the button" /// also use camel case
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextEditor(text: $document.text) /// pass in the `projectedValue`
            Divider()
            TextEditor(text: $newTextEditor) /// pass in the `projectedValue`
                .padding()
            Button("test", action: dosomething)
        }
    }
    
    func dosomething() {
        newTextEditor = document.text /// set the `wrappedValue`
    }
}
```